# How to setup Selenium Webdriver, Capybara, and Rails Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am currently running WSL2. I have installed `google-chrome-stable` and `chromedriver` in the system.

`google-chrome-stable`: Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131

`chromedriver`: ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.43

```rb
# Gemfile

group :test do
  gem "capybara", ">= 3.26"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

```rb
# test/application_system_test_case.rb

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome do |option|
    option.add_argument "no-sandbox"
  end
end
```

```rb
# test/system/users_test.rb

class UsersTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  def setup
    Capybara.app_host = "http://app.example.com/"
  end

  test "user sign up" do
    visit new_user_path
    fill_in "user[name]", with: "Jane Hemmingway"
    fill_in "user[email]", with: "jane@example.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: "secret_password"
    click_button "get started"

    assert_redirected_to accounts_path
  end
end
```

But when I run this test, it throws an error.

```sh
Error:
UsersTest#test_user_sign_up:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.131)
    test/system/users_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersTest>'
```

I'm confused about what this error means. Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: Instead of `option.add_argument "no-sandbox"` can you try `option.add_argument "--no-sandbox"`

Comment: Ok, so I think I know what the problem is. `Capybara.app_host = "http://app.example.com/"` is the culprit here. When I remove this and change my routes, the tests run successfully.

Comment: But, the routes have a subdomain constraint. So how do I make capybara visit routes with the `app` subdomain? Any clues? If I override `Capybara.app_host` the tests fail with the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so instead of setting `Capybara.app_host` as `http://app.example.com/`, we need to set it to `http://app.lvh.me`.

We also need to tell capybara to always include the port.

```rb
# test/application_system_test_case.rb

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.always_include_port = true
end
```

Now the tests runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is telling you what the problem is.  `www.example.com` isn't resolving to an ip address on whatever machine the browser is being launched on.